# send a object in the rails form_tag method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not able to send a object using the rails form_tag form helper. I have tried the following

```
Download:<%=form_tag({controller: "orders", action: "csv_downloader",format: "csv"}, method: "post") do%>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag(:data, @orders_customs_display) %>
                    <%= submit_tag ("Download CSV"),:class => "btn btn-success download" %>
                  <% end %>
```

In the view and in the controller I have the following

```
  def csv_downloader
    data=params[:data]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.csv { send_data data.to_csv }
      end
  end
```

In the routes I have the following:

```
  match "csv_downloader", to: "orders#csv_downloader", via: [:post]
```

As you see the .to_csv is a custom function written in the order.rb model

```
  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |order|
        csv << order.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

When I try downloading I get the following error.

```
 undefined method `to_csv' for #<String:0x0000000716f8a8>
```

This is essentially the argument is coming as a string and not as an object? How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send strings or files via html forms but you cannot send complex object.

What you can do: Serialize the object (Marshal) into a hidden string field and deserialize the string into an object later on the controller again. But this may be insecure because the user might be able to change the serialized data.

The preferred way would be to recreate the data in the same way like it was done for the html view, but just not to render the view but to send a csv file.